# Thumbing with both hands

Tags: carrom

Can we use both the hands while thumbing the coins in carrom board or are we limited to single hand only.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and also appears to be two questions.  Could you please clarify.

Comment: I've removed the second question. It can be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

Under IV: How to strike in the official rules

> 35. Any hand may be used in play.

Hand in this case is singular. This is somewhat clarified further down...

> 37. The elbow of the playing “hand” shall not come within the playing surface nor shall extend beyond the imaginary lines of the arrows. The “hand” may, however, cross the arrow.

This indicates that there should only be one hand in use.

The rules also indicate what the other hand could be used for

> 38. While making a stroke, taking support of the Stool or Chair, Stand or Table of the C/B or keeping the legs on the rim of the stand or table by the player is not permissible. However, hands may rest on his body and legs or on the rim of the stool or chair on which he sits.

Furthermore, if you wanted to make an analogy with cue-sports, there is almost always a rule against double stroking or push strokes, as the concept of a "stroke" is one single instantaneous point of contact. Carrom's definition gives some more leeway because we're using fingers instead of cue sticks, but the concept is still the same. Using two fingers undoubtedly results in striking the striker twice.

Answer (score 0):

Either hand could be used for thumbing but not both at the same time.

Ref: https://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm

IV. HOW TO STRIKE
35) Any hand may be used in play.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When answering a question, it is a best-practice to cite (and link to) a specific source for your answer. These sources provide an authoritative reference and make it easier for the OP to select the Right answer based on objective standards, instead of what could be just a subjective opinion. I would suggest updating your answer with a link to the rules where you found this information.

Answer (score -2):

You can shoot with **either** hand and thumbing is allowed:
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-thumbing-allowed-in-the-international-Carrom-game

Comment: Hi lhmit, and welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange. We don't generally accept link-only answers here: [you can see "your answer is in another castle" for why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). We prefer answers to include the important parts of their link, in this case, citing the rules themselves that allow this would be appropriate and the link itself isn't necessary. Pretend the link became a 404 tomorrow (it very well could): what would you include your answer to keep it relevant and reliable?